# Is there a battle tested way of matching DOM elements between browser render and version stored in the CMS?

Tags: javascript, html, typescript, hash

I am working on a small project to dynamically update  tags on blog posts.

The blog posts are stored in a CMS as text, and I have a javascript snippet embedded on the blog post page.

I'd like to be able to identify matching  tags between the data stored in the CMS and what the javascript sees on the page.

My current approach is to concatenate several features of each  element and create a hash, something like:

```
import { createHash } from "crypto";
createHash("sha256")
    .update(
      link.href +
      link.parent_inner_text +
      link.text_content
    )
    .digest("base64");
```

I'm running into a small issue where the `parent_inner_text` (`parentNode.innerText`) is different between the CMS and the page due to how white space is being handled - I'm seeing `"\n"` on the page, but in the CMS that's not present. This is due to CSS rules applied during rendering.

Before I spend too much time trying to normalise the whitespace so it's not a problem or change the features I'm using for the hash, I'd like to hear if there's a more robust approach that I should be considering.